# Two applications in crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, hybrid, ad-hoc-distribution

I am wondering how to distribute 2 apps one made with a native implementation and another with a hybrid one.

I can have the same name for them from what I can see, but I think I will have issues at the bundle id.

I want a group of testers to receive the iOS one and the others the hybrid one and I don't want them to know which is which.

(I am interested only for iOS currently, but input for android is welcomed as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable with a few manual dependencies. Here's what you need to do:

1. Onboard the native iOS/Android app on crashlytics with your Org's API key and Build Secret.
2. Use the same bundle id, Fabric API Key and Build secret (basically everything same) in your hybrid app.
3. Distribute 2 apps, 1 native and 1 hybrid, every time. All distributions will go to the same beta dashboard. It depends on you, how you keep track of which one is which (native or hybrid) since all distributions will look the same on beta dashboard.
4. Here comes the manual part. Each time you randomly select which testers gets native/hybrid app.

NOTE: This should work for both iOS and Android.

Comment: If I distribute two builds will they have the build number different or how can I tell them apart? I need to know which is which so I can send them to the right person.

Comment: It depends on you. You can either set different build numbers or have some indicator in the release notes for yourself.

Comment: It should work as proposed @Chintan. In my case I found that the best solution is to have them with separate IDs and keep the difference to a small detail (like a dash or capital letter)